# Break up a string by words an punctionation

Tags: php, string, preg-match-all

To split up a string, I come up with...

```
<php
    preg_match_all('/(\w)|(,.!?;)/', "I'm a little teapot, short and stout.", $matches);
    print_r($matches[0]);
```

I thought this would separate each word (\w) and the specified punctuation (,.!?;).
For example: `["I'm", "a", "little", "teapot", ",", "short", "and", "stout", "."]`

Instead I get:

```
Array
(
    [0] => I
    [1] => m
    [2] => a
    [3] => l
    [4] => i
    [5] => t
    [6] => t
    [7] => l
    [8] => e
    [9] => t
    [10] => e
    [11] => a
    [12] => p
    [13] => o
```

etc...

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You have two faults:

1. The `\w` matches only a single character. You want to match multiple by `\w+`. Furthermore `\w` matches only alphanumeric characters. If you want to match other characters like `'` you will need to include them: `[\w']`.
2. The `(,.!?;)` matches the character sequence `,.!?;`. Instead you want to match any of these characters using `[,.!?;]`.

The correct regex is:

```
'/[\w\']+|[,.!?;]/'
```

If you want to be more permissive you should use unicode character classes instead (allows letters, numbers, combining marks, dash characters and the apostrophe for words and punctuation for punctuation):

```
'/[\pL\pN\pM\pPd\']+|\pP/u'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this - sure it works as you want:

```
([\w]+)|[,.!?;]+
```

Also want to share with you one very useful service - [online regex tester](http://regexhero.net/tester/)

Comment: a) no need to put the \w into a char group b) the second part should be a char group, not a capturing.

Comment: 1) Are you sure author didnt want to fetch words? 2) oops... =)

Comment: a) Yes, he want's to fetch words. But if you don't want to add further characters to be matched, you can just write `\w+`, you don't need to surround it with brackets ;)

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try something like:

```
/([^,.!?; ]+)|(,.!?;)/
```